# How to express set membership in SMTLIB format in Z3?

Tags: z3, smt, cvc4

I'm trying to use the SMTLIB format to express set membership in Z3:

```
(declare-const a (Set Int))

;; the next two lines parse correctly in CVC4, but not Z3:
(assert (= a (as emptyset (Set Int))))
(assert (member 12 a))

;; these work in both solvers
(assert (= a (union a a)))
(assert (subset a a))
(assert (= a (intersection a a)))
(check-sat)
```

The functions `emptyset` and `member` seem to parse as expected in CVC4, but not in Z3.

From checking the API (e.g., here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html), Z3 **does** support empty sets and membership programatically, but how does one express these in SMTLIB syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed annoying z3 and CVC4 use slightly different notations for sets. In z3, a set is essentially an array with the range of bool. Based on this analogy, your program is coded as:

```
(declare-const a (Set Int))

(assert (= a ((as const (Set Int)) false)))
(assert (select a 12))

(assert (= a (union a a)))
(assert (subset a a))
(assert (= a (intersection a a)))
(check-sat)
```

which z3 accepts as is and produces `unsat`. But you'll find that CVC4 doesn't like this program now.

It would be great if the SMTLib movement standardized the theory of sets (http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/) and there has indeed been a proposal along these lines (https://www.kroening.com/smt-lib-lsm.pdf) but I don't think it has been adopted by solvers nor sanctioned by the SMTLib committee yet.